# After updating to Ubuntu 15.04 all my printers print once then cannot connect

Tags: printing

After updating to Ubuntu 15.04 all my printers, Epson Artisan 837, HP Officejet Pro  8500, and copiers, Lexmark XC2100 and Toshiba 287CS print once then cannot connect. I've tried deleting the printers and reinstalling them. If I readdress the printer or move the print job to another printer, sometimes it works but usually I reboot the computer. I really don't want to have to reinstall Ubuntu. Can you help? Computer is an Acer 5534. This is on three different wifi networks, home and both churches I serve.

Comment: Okay. I didn't hear from anyone so I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 15.04 and I get the same problem. I print once and all is good. I print a second time and the status is "Processing - Not connected? What am I doing wrong? Am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: Nope, I have the same issue as well. Had my printer working and now in 15.04 it says not connected?

Comment: What does up-vote mean?

Comment: From the site's help page: [Vote Up](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up)